# Admob in PhoneGap + ChildBrowser (without any other plugin)?

Tags: cordova, admob, childbrowser

I would like to ask, is possible to use AdMob (or other) service without plugins for concrete OS? I want just add some Javascript in my code and open adds link directly via ChildBrowser plugin, is it possible and is any helpful tutorial?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge -- no way.

Read [this extended answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14842904/1469208) to my question, to get a brief discussion on most popular mobile ads networks. As you can see from this text, [MobFox](http://mobfox.com/), is the only (known to me) mobile ads provider, that supports displaying ads via JavaScript.

If you want to display AdMob ads in your iOS app, you have to compile your app directly on local version of PhoneGap (not through PhoneGap Build), which will give you access to external container for your HTML5 content. You can then modify Java code of that container to add AdMob adds to your app.

There were many articles written about this (like [the one at PhoneGap Wiki](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/In-App-Advertisements)). You will also find many answers here in StackOverflow, posts in many blogs and information in many sources in the Interent.