# Html Phonegapp ios app

Tags: php, cordova, phonegap-build

I built a small app with HTML, jQuery, and jQuery Mobile and all on top of PhoneGap to public to the App Store and run on iOS.

My problem is that every link or every ad that I have inside opens into an InAppBrowser/WebUiView and I don't know how to have a back button.

All my pages except index.html are loading inside my app with .load().

So I want hyperlinks, admob ads, or other ads to open in normal browser or if it's necessary to open inside the app then I need a back button.

Also, do you believe that an app like this with PhoneGap will pass Apple's review processes so it can be available on the App Store?

I spent too many hours doing modifications without luck!

Here is a sample code of my project:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Mobile App</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile_css/style.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquerymobile/demos/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquerymobile/demos/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type='application/javascript' src='js/fastclick.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            FastClick.attach(document.body);
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".secondpage").click(function(){
                $("#secondpageholder").load("http://www.mydomain.com/secondpage.html", function() { 
                    $("#secondpageholder").fadeIn("fast");
                });
            });
        });
    </script> 
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos ui-responsive-panel" id="panel-responsive-page1" data-title="Test">

        <div style="width:320px; height:40px; margin:0 auto;">
            <div class="secondpage">
                <img src="nextpage.png">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both;"></div>

        <div style="width:320px; height:15px; color: #000; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:10px;">
            <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/anotherpageExternalPage.html" target="_blank">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div id="secondpageholder" style="width:320px; height:15px; color: #000; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:10px; display:none;">
    </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.celebrityposted.appcpca"
        version   = "1.0.0">

    <name>Mydomain.Com</name>

    <description>
        My description.
    </description>

    <author href="http://www.mydomain.com" email="info@mydomain.com">
        C Team
    </author>

    <!--
        If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
        following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
        permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
    -->
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <preference name="phonegap-version"           value="3.3.0" />          <!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
    <preference name="orientation"                value="portrait" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->    
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="7" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->

    <!-- MY IOS -->
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen"                value="false"/>
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="true"/>
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"                value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"              value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"               value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"                 value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"         value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback"        value="true"/>
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator"            value="black"/>
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner"         value="true"/>
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering"  value="false"/>
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"                 value="false" />

    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </feature>

    <!-- Plugins -->

    <!-- Core plugins -->
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <!--<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />-->
    <!--<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />-->
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <!--<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />-->
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />-->
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />-->
    <!--<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />-->
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <!--<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />

    <!-- Third party plugins -->
    <!-- A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins -->
    <!-- 
        <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
    -->

    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>

    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />

    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"         gap:platform="blackberry" />

    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />

    <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />


    <access origin="*" />
    <access uri="*" />


</widget>
```

I hope someone help me!

Answer (score 0):

While i was working with a project  i build an application for tablet and iPad with my seniors . we build an Base Model which is used by all other we bind it with other and initially all the script loads and we make a container having main page which is dynamic . Our  application has successfully passed from app store .

Comment: And how is it possible to add admob inside my project? do you know?

Comment: Is it possible to add AdMob ads inside my app? And also how is it possible to open all links on external browser and not inside app browser?

Comment: you can see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841790/any-way-to-display-admob-ads-or-other-ad-provider-in-pure-javascript